# PHP - HTML Entities/Special Chars Confusion

Tags: php, html, html-entities

I'm working with a database and comparing values to strings to then create new records. I've encountered an issue with a comparison with a database value that is stored in a $type variable - the offending value is:

```
<recordID>
```

In my PHP script I do a test to see if the database value = "":

```
if ($type == '<recordID>') {
// create new records etc
}
```

however I've just noticed this test is failing, and I'm assuming it's the "<" and ">" characters that is the issue. If I echo the $type variable I get this in the browser source view:

```
&lt;contactID&gt;
```

I can see the issue relates to htmlentities and html special chars but I haven't been able to work out the function to use to be able to get this comparison above to work.

Comment: I didn't want to hardcode this - I was hoping to be able to use a PHP function to convert/encode/decode on the fly as necessary, but will do this if that's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use builtin for it

```
<?php
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($type);
?>
```